# Lotus Notes C# Interop, trying to execute Send/Receive Mail

Tags: c#, lotus-notes, interop-domino

From a .NET C# Winform app I am automating Lotus Notes and would like to run the "Send/Receive Email" Action to download POP3 email from Gmail.

Trawling through the object browser for Interop.Domino I can't see any obvious methods - does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the Run method of NotesAgent class to execute a formula agent containing @Command( [ReplicatorSendReceiveMail] ).  This is the only way I can think of, but I'm not that confident in this approach.  That's because NotesAgent is part of the back-end classes, and ReplicatorSendReceiveMail is a Notes client function.  The back-end classes generally don't have access to Notes client functions, but you never know... it might work.